# Code a message box when a workbook is selected

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to make a macro so when the workbook is opened or when it becomes active (meaning that its not active when its running in the background but the user is working in another workbook or in another application) there comes a dialog box with a customized warning message. Ideally the code would look something like this and would be in the ThisWorkbook Object code:

```
Sub warningmsg()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb as This.Workbook
If wb.first.mouseclick <> True 
Then
    MsgBox "Warning, this workbook is HOT"
end sub
```

How is this possible in Excel VBA?

Comment: When exactly would this code run? And what would cause the MsgBox to appear? The question, currently, is not specific enough.

Comment: The event of the user opening the workbook or activating the workbook after doing something else should trigger the message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the below code in the `ThisWorkbook` code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    MsgBox "this workbook is hot"
End Sub
```

Save and close file (make sure you use an extension that contains macros, *.xlsm for instance*).

Open it again, and open another workbook. Switching between windows and activating the one that has the above code in it will cause the MsgBox to appear and show your `this workbook is hot` string

Comment: thank you, it works like you say, but when I click on another window e.g. the browser and then back it does not pop up like I would like

Comment: @steinbitur that is how to Workbook_Activate() event works. You cannot overwrite this behavior. It only works between workbooks.